# How to prove without computation that group under multiplication modulo $n$ when $n =25$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found the above problem in Herstein's Topics In Algebra book . Ofcourse doing computation for hour one can prove that the group mentioned in question is cyclic but i think author want's reader to think of any other idea.

Comment: $2$ is a generator for any group of the $(\mathbb{Z}/5^m\mathbb{Z})^*$ kind. Just apply Hensel's lifting lemma.

Comment: Define "without computation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy to see that $2^{10}=1024 \equiv 24 \equiv -1$ mod $25$. Hence $2$ has order $20=|(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z})^*|=\varphi(25)$.

Comment: which theorem / lemma you applied ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, with the information you have there, the order could be $4$, so you need to check that $2^4 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 25$, which admittedly is pretty obvious!

Comment: Lagrange, and just picking the first element after the neutral element and then checking powers (read, and here Langrange chimes in, divisors of $20$, so $1,2,4,5,10$  (for which you do not need pen and paper)).